# Django application only working with port 8000

Tags: python, django, amazon-ec2, webserver, web-hosting

I am working on an project and I have hosted it on EC2 to see if everything is working fine or not.
It's only a single page application for now with no endpoint.

Problem is it only works if I use `my_domain:8000` or `my_ip:8000`.

Here is the config file I have written:

```
server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name mydomain.info;

    # to avoid any error while fetching fevicon
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location /static/ {
        root /home/ubuntu/dev/myproject;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        # communicate via socket file created by Gunicorn
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/dev/myproject.sock;
    }
}
```

I enabled it using:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/config-file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

After doing that, I restarted `nginx` using:

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

Then started server using:

```
python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

It's my first time doing this and I think I have done something wrong with config file or while enabling it but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Why would you expect it to respond on port 80, if you have explicitly told nginx to listen on port 8000? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you are using nginx and gunicorn

- setup gunicorn
- configure and run your nginx to listen port 80 instead of 8000

Then nginx will proxy pass the django requests to the gunicorn.

> When you run python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000, django
> development server is starting, (which is not suitable for
> production), instead use gunicorn, Create a gunicron unit file and
> enable and start it.

/etc/nginx/config-file

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name your_ip_address;

    client_body_buffer_size 10k;
    .......   
   

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/ubuntu/dev/myproject;
    }
    location /media/  {
        root /home/ubuntu/dev/content;
    }
    
    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/dev/myproject.sock;
        proxy_read_timeout 120;
    }
}
```

create a gunicorn service file
/etc/systemd/system/my_gunicorn.service

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=nginx
WorkingDirectory=/root/project/myproject
ExecStart=/path to env/bin/gunicorn --workers 4 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/dev/myproject.sock <myproject>.wsgi:application --access-logfile /var/log/gunicorn/access.log --error-logfile /var/log/gunicorn/error.log 

Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After start the gunicorn service and nignx,
Follow the link for complete details to configure nignx-gunicorn-django.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04.

Also check your aws security groups.

Comment: hey, everything is running but still I can not get the app on domain even thogh it is working with gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 myproject.wsgi. this is how I have done my static files- STATIC_URL = '/staticfiles/'
MEDIA_URL = '/images/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles'). I have updated my post also with config file.

Comment: add port 8000 in aws security group,    ( after testing run gunicron locally)